# Baumslag-Solitar group BS(1,2) is torsion-free

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, torsion-groups

I need to show that the Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,2)$ is torsion-free. It is given by

$$BS(1,2) = \langle a,t \mid tat^{-1} = a^2\rangle$$

I have taken a non-trivial element $g$ from $BS(1,2)$. I assumed it is of finite order and tried to play with it, in order to get contradiction, with no luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

${\rm BS}(1,2)$ has a normal subgroup $N = \langle a^G \rangle$ with $G/N$ infinite cyclic, so a torsion element would be contained in $N$. But $N$ is isomorphic to the additive subgroup $\{ a2^n : a,n \in {\mathbb Z} \}$ of ${\mathbb Q}$ and so is torsion-free.

Comment: Very elegant. +1

Comment: Thanks,
Why is G/N infinite cyclic though?

Comment: That follows directly from the presentation. $G/N = \langle a,t \mid tat^{-1}=a^2, a=1 \rangle \cong \langle t \mid \rangle$.

Comment: @slade Sorry, there was a typo. The $b$ in my definition of $N$ should have been $2$. It is not true that $\langle a \rangle$ is normal in $G$ because $t^{-1}at$ is not in $\langle a \rangle$ - it is a square root of $a$. And it is not true that every element can be written in the from $a^sb^t$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Okay, I see my mistake—in $\langle a\rangle$ we can conjugate by $t$ but not $t^{-1}$.  Is it straightforward to see the isomorphism?